# Unable to upload seed data with Attachinary gem "Undefined method `photos_urls=' for object"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload seed data for my Photoshoot model which consists of multiple for urls like so:

```
10.times {
  urls = [
    'http://lorempixel.com/400/400/',
    'http://lorempixel.com/400/400/',
    'http://lorempixel.com/400/400/',
    'http://lorempixel.com/400/400/',
    'http://lorempixel.com/400/400/',
    'http://lorempixel.com/400/400/',
    'http://lorempixel.com/400/400/',
    'http://lorempixel.com/400/400/'
  ]
  time = Faker::Time.between(DateTime.now - 1, DateTime.now + 3)
  photoshoot = Photoshoot.new( user_id: Faker::Number.between(1, 19), photograph_id: Faker::Number.between(1, 19), start_time: time, end_time: time + Faker::Number.between(1, 2).hours, message: Faker::TheFreshPrinceOfBelAir.quote )
  photoshoot.save!
  photoshoot.photo_urls = urls
}
```

But I'm getting the following error message in my seed:

*NoMethodError: undefined method `photos_urls=' for*

My model is the following :

```
class Photoshoot < ApplicationRecord
  has_attachment :photos, maximum: 20
  belongs_to :photograph
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add attachment path

```
has_attached_file :photo,
:styles => {
:thumb=> "",
:small  => ""},
:path => "uploads/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:basename.:extension",
:url => "uploads/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```